# Single word to describe positive, matured, or loving attitude towards life

Tags: single-word-requests

I am planning to create a new [Twitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter) or [Facebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook) account and my own website, which will be used to share happiness, awareness, positivity, motivation, related images/quotes to the people who follow/subscribe it.

I want to decide a good name for the website domain or you can say Facebook page/Twitter account username.

I need some suggestions to show following qualities:

- I love to face challenges, I never give up
- I love life **a lot**
- I love family,social friends and **strangers** too
- I believe in constantly progressing in life, I never regret

In short, **I don't have any single complaint to life; it is very beautiful and amazing, I love to live *each second* of the day**.

Comment: Go for the first.

Comment: @user: I need some suggestion of single word which can describe above attitude.

Comment: *[Pollyanna](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pollyanna)* or *[Pangloss](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Panglossian)* would have worked, except that domain names pollyanna.com and pangloss.com are already taken.

Comment: @jwpat7: It sounds really good but as you said it is unavailable.It would be great if you can suggest some unique name.and yes,thanks for your valuable time which you have spend in checking for availability of domain.

Comment: halcyon.com and halcyon.net also appear to be taken.  You might go thru a list of synonyms of *[serene](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=serene&send=Look+it+up)* and [serenity](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=serenity&send=Look+it+up) or [optimistic](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=optimistic&send=Look+it+up) or [cheerful](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=cheerful)  and see if any appeal to you.

Comment: Here on this Q&A site, you will have to ask the question in a different way, or it could be closed as 'not constructive'.

Comment: @jwpat7:let's forget about the domain availability as of now,can you suggest few more unique words like 8-10 names and post it as answer so that I can accept it and I can even choose good one from them.at the end,I will think to go for `.in` or `.co.in` suffix if `.com` will be unavailable.so just provide some more suggestions without worrying about the domain availability.

Comment: @Kris: I will keep your suggestion in mind for sure :-)

Comment: I assume English is not your first language? You may want to employ a proof-reader to ensure proper spelling, capitalisation and punctuation on your site if you care for the English language and don't want to turn off people who do enjoy well-written content.

Comment: @teylyn: I will do that later on,right now I am searching for a good name of my product.

Comment: It just strikes me that you don't use proper punctuation. A full stop or a comma is always followed by a space, please. That will make reading your text (even in questions here) much easier. Do us the favour.

Comment: @teylyn: feel free to edit the question.

Comment: I already did that before I posted the comment. You can see the edits to learn where your punctuation and capitalisation is wanting.

Comment: re: "I will do that later on ..." On ELU, it is a prerequisite. Editing by peers is **not** for your grammatical and punctuation errors.

Comment: @Kris: "I will do that later on ..." was the reply of your suggestion "You may want to employ a proof-reader to ensure proper spelling, capitalisation and punctuation on your site".

Comment: That was not my comment, but teylyn's.

Comment: @Kris: my mistake,but you can see that the reply was for suggestion regarding website only and you took it in wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no substitute for going through synonym lists for yourself, as suggested in comments ([1](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=serene&send=Look+it+up),[2](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=serenity&send=Look+it+up),[3](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=optimistic&send=Look+it+up),[4](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=cheerful); also [5](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=merry),[6](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=bright)), which include words like 
*[blithe](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blithe)*, *[breezy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/breezy)*, *[bright](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bright)*, *[cheerful](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cheerful)*, *[ecstatic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ecstatic)*, *[euphoric](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/euphoric)*, *[gleeful](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gleeful)*, *[happy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/happy)*, *[jaunty](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jaunty)*, *[jolly](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jolly)*, *[jovial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jovial)*, *[joyful](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/joyful)*, *[joyous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/joyous)*, *[merry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/merry)*, *[optimistic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/optimist)*, *[pleasant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pleasant)*, *[propitious](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/propitious)*, *[radiant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/radiant)*.  Also *[halcyon](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/halcyon#Adjective)*, with its senses  “Calm, undisturbed, peaceful, serene” and  “Pertaining to the halcyon or *[kingfisher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingfisher)*”.

Comment: I will follow your suggestions.Thanks a lot for the help !!